# How to switch between users from command prompt or powershell?

Tags: command-line, powershell

On my computer I have 3 user accounts (eg User1, User2 and User3).
I am User1 and my kids have User2 and User3.

I want to create a shortcut to a batch file or some app that can switch/login to User2 or User3, but I don't want to use the runas command.

PS: I want to create a shortcut, because they will not connect to their user

Comment: Have you tried `tsdiscon`   ?

Comment: how? tsdicon disconnects the user

Comment: I see two approaches: (1) The simplistic : have the children do `runas` of Explorer to have a desktop running under that account (if this works - never tried it). (2) Do a real login, where the shortcut changes the default login and logs out and automatically in, except that this would require elevation for registry updates.

Comment: Are you wanting to just run an app as a certain user OR switch the whole environment (GUI)? tsdicon (file not on Win10 home) will present you with a lock screen where you can switch to the other user. Ctrl+Alt+Del, down, Enter might do same thing (else Ctrl+L). If you're wanting to entirely automate that process I'm not sure you can to be honest